# How do I make hair stand

Tags: particles

So I'm doing a golden eagle and I want to use the particle system to display rectangles with feather textures as hairs. Is there a way I can use shape keys to make the hair stand in a....kinda aggressive manner?

Comment: Not sure, but shape keys don't sound like the adequate tool. You might be able to achieve a similar effect with [Animation Nodes Addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vxc4P0YI2rI)